# ASP .NET change it to default view

Tags: asp.net

How can I change the ASP .NET to default view? When I have first run the index.html it looked as follows (Default view), then after updating the NuGet it changed the way page's view as shown below (Changed view):

Default view:
[image: Default view:]

Changed view:

[image]

Comment: Roll back the nuget packages? (I assume it was bootstrap).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did roll back before posting this question here.

Comment: This is style-sheet issue. Since Bootstrap is used on templates with Asp.net web apps you've probably upgraded your bootstrap.

Comment: Mosia Thabo I thank you for your response, how can I fix this issue?